# Laravel 5: how to prefill response from hasMeny

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new in Laravel and I can't found how to do next:
There are entites Books, Chapters and Recepis.

Recepis belongs to book by book_id FK.
Chapters belongs to book by book_id FK.

Recpies and Chapters are not linked through DB. But I need to linke them on next logic. Each Recepi has page number where is located in book and each chapter has range of pages strat_page to end_page.

When I call book->find(id) from controller I need to get json like:

```
{
            "id": 132,
            "isbn": "xxx-xx-xx-xxx-x",
            "title": "Bartje BOOK”,
            "author_id": 8,
            "publisher_id": 6,
            chapters:[
                {
                    title : "kidkdk"
                    startpage: 1
                    endpage: 10
                    recepis: [
                        {
                            recepie_id: 1,
                            title: "uyuy",
                            image: "http://kfsklkldkfldkf"
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            title: "ysysy",
                            image: "http://kfsklkldkfldkf"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Is there any posibility to do some logic in Book->chapters() method?

Answer (score 1):

Please Make a DB Structure as per below

- Books -- id,book_name,...
- Chapters -- id,book_id,chapter_name,....
- Recepis --  id,chapter_id,recepis_name,....

Now in modal make a relationship

- In Books Modal

  public function Chapters(){
   return $this->hasMany(Chapters::class,'book_id');
  }
- In Chapters Modal

  public function Recepis(){
       return $this->hasMany(Recepis::class,'chapter_id');
  }
  -- Now in Controller Write..

  $data = Book::with(['Chapters'=>function($q){return $q->with('Recepis');}])->find($id);

You will get a Object as per Your question
i Hope you got it.

Comment: This would be nice, but this is existing project and I need to ad chapter entity now, without updating existing data for recepis.

Comment: Hello if you want to this type of output than you must have to update this type of reletionship .. and other way is you can yous a simple join..